# How to align TextView in image center

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am try to display a textview in image center, but not working in LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/kurtis"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@mipmap/kurtis" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_text="Testing" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/salwars"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@mipmap/salwar" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_text="Testing"/>
```

Any one have idea please help me.
I edited my question, this is my problem.

Comment: I will suggest you to use Relative Layout and then, having aligned in layout_centerInParent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, for example, use `RelativeLayout` to center your `TextView` over the `ImageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="325dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kurtis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/salwar"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_text="Testing"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="325dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/salwars"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/salwar"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_text="Testing"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Also, you should put your image into the drawable folders, not mipmap. Mipmap is specifically for launcher icons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FrameLayout for that. It centers all its childs, like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="325dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kurtis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/kurtis" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Testing"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="325dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/salwar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/salwar" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Testing"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay